# How to update an Option box (select proper case) from a returned value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple GET form that is an option box.
The GET form is sent when user has selected his choice and clicked the button.

Then, GET form is dealt at server side and it returns a value contained into a returned variable named : ~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~

~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~ could then be one of the option value from the list.

ie, let say ~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~ has returned '2'.
then, how could get the choice with option value dynamicaly selected on the option box ?

Is it possible to update the real state of an option box from a returned value with Javascript ?

I don't see how i could do this.

Many thanks for your help,

```html
<form method="get" action="in-out.htm" id="sensor_1">

  <select name="schedule" value="~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~">
  <option value="0">never</option>
  <option value="1">every 5 minutes</option>
  <option value="2">every 10 minutes</option>
  <option value="3">every 15 minutes</option>
  <option value="4">every 30 minutes</option>
  <option value="5">every hour</option>
  <option value="6">every 2 hours</option>
  <option value="7">every 4 hours</option>
  <option value="8">every 8 hours</option>
  <option value="9">every 12 hours</option>
  <option value="10">everyday</option>
  <option value="11">every week</option>
  <option value="12">every month</option>
  <option value="13">every 6 months</option>
  <option value="14">every year</option></select>
        <input src="./checked.png"onclick="document.getElementById('sensor_1').submit()" align="center" type="image">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `setSelected` function:

```
 function setSelected(val){
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("schedule").options;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].value == val)
        elements[i].selected = true;
      else
        elements[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
```

Once you get the value into `maj_sensor_schedule`, do this:

```
setSelected(maj_sensor_schedule);
```

Comment: Thanks to your code i'm able to get val as the expected value.  However the form choice is not updated accordingly. Should i call the function into the form ? i did so.  I also have several option form with same name in my page.  if i place the function into the form to be update, will the function update only that form or all having same name in the webpage ?